# refer to a data frame that was dynamically created

Tags: r

I need to create data frames dynamically and refer to them. So far I can create data frame dynamically like:

```
master<-c("bob","ed","frank")
d<-seq(1:10)
for (i in 1:length(master)){
  assign(master[i], d )
}

ed[6]
```

now if I do

```
ls()
```

I can see there is an "ed" object. I want to refer to an manipulate the data in it WITHOUT referring to the name.

i.e. instead of doing "ed[6]"

I want to have "ed"  in a variable like:

```
master[2][6] # BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

or

```
df<-"ed" #this does not work either
df[6]
```

The point of me naming the data frames dynamically was so I can refer to them dynamically. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [get](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).

```
get(master[2])[5]
get(master[2])[2]
```

If you want to set values, you need to use [assign](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html). But be careful, it assign values as a whole. What I mean is that you can not set one value of vector, you need to set whole vector.

```
master<-c("bob","ed","frank")
d<-seq(1:10)
for (i in 1:length(master)){
  assign(master[i], d )
}

ed[6]

get(master[2])[5]
get(master[2])[2]

temp <- get(master[2])

# assign value 20 to index 5
assign("ed",20)

assign("ed[6]",20) # it creates a variable named "ed[6]", not what you want

ls(pattern = "^ed.*$")

temp[6] = 20

assign("ed",temp)
rm(temp) # remove temp if you do not need it

get("ed")[6]
```

Comment: Can I then set value too? like get(master[2])[5] <- 600? that returns an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` as Atilla suggests, but for a case like this you may be better off creating a list and then referring to objects by list index instead. It's tidier to create one object then a whole bunch, and referencing the contents is simple.

```
# create empty list  
my_list <- list()

# put stuff in the list    
for (i in 1:length(master)) {
  my_list[[i]] <- d
}

# get the 6th element from the 2nd object in my_list
my_list[[2]][6]
```